# Verificar se todos itens tem mesmo valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, como verificar se todos itens "`estoqueLevel`" tem mesmo valor ("0" no caso).

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response), function (i, modosEntrega) {

        for (var i in modosEntrega) {

            var foraEstoque = modosEntrega[i].estoqueLevel;

            $(foraEstoque).each(function () {

                if(foraEstoque == "0") {

                    $('.class').remove();                       

                }

            });            

        }

    });
```

**json:**

```
{"modosEntrega":[

  {
   "nome" : "MO00002000",
   "dias" : "2",
   "preco" : "R$ 11,00",
   "estoqueLevel" : "0"

  },
  {
   "name" : "5003",
   "dias" : "7",
   "preco" : "R$ 2,20",
   "estoqueLevel" : "0"

  }
]}
```

Comment: apresente o html e o json

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, você está fazendo um foreach no "estoqueLevel", mas ele não é um array, ele está dentro de cada item do array "modosEntrega". Eu fiz um loop com base no seu objeto para você ter como referência

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {"modosEntrega":[

  {
   "nome" : "MO00002000",
   "dias" : "2",
   "preco" : "R$ 11,00",
   "estoqueLevel" : "0"

  },
  {
   "name" : "5003",
   "dias" : "7",
   "preco" : "R$ 2,20",
   "estoqueLevel" : "0"

  }
]}
 $.each(data, function(index, item) {
   for (var i in item) {
 foraEstoque = item[i].estoqueLevel;
 if(foraEstoque == "0") {
  console.log('fora estoque');
 }
   }
 });
```